# Haver-de + infinitivo em Portugal

Tags: expressões, português-europeu, haver

A expressão "haver de", que serve para expressar a intenção de realizar uma ação no futuro, não é comum no português coloquial do Brasil, pois soa muito "poética" atualmente. Normalmente, mesmo para enfatizar a ação ou deixá-la mais formal, é utilizado o futuro, como por exemplo:

> Um dia eu escreverei um livro. / Um dia eu irei escrever um livro.
>
> = Um dia eu hei-de escrever um livro. (poético no Brasil)

Eu gostaria de saber se é a mesma coisa em Portugal, pois em alguns livros que ensinam português europeu como segunda língua há muitos exemplos e exercícios para a prática desta expressão. A impressão que tenho é que ainda se usa isto na linguagem coloquial portuguesa.

Answer (score 5):

Sim, usa-se muito na linguagem coloquial, mas também poética.

O valor de futuro (pelo menos hoje, futuro indeterminado) que referes nem sempre é muito claro, contudo. A perífrase tem uma componente fortemente modal: «não me hei de esquecer de ti» (promessa), «hei de cá voltar» (promessa para um futuro indeterminado), «hás de te arrepender» (ameaça), «quando voltares, hás de me trazer um copo» (pedido), «hás de ir ver a exposição» (sugestão/obrigação muito fraca), «ele há de melhorar» (desejo), «ele (com certeza) já lá há de estar» (aqui com valor epistémico, perto do futuro simples). A natureza compromissiva é mais comum na 1.ª pessoa, especialmente no singular.

No passado, a componente modal ainda é mais clara («havias de ir lá» é uma forma menos forte de dizer «devias ir lá»), embora também possamos encontrar casos em que se aproxima do futuro do pretérito, sem qualquer valor modal (por exemplo, numa narrativa: «mais tarde nesse dia, ainda havia de chover (=choveria) outra vez»). Ou, agora já com alguma componente modal, numa construção condicional: «hás de ir ver a exposição, **havias de gostar**/ias gostar»

O uso mais comum, ainda assim, deve ser em frases interrogativas como estas:

> — Não sei o que hei de fazer.
>   — Que havemos de fazer?

Estas frases são geralmente retóricas (resposta: não há nada que possamos fazer).

O uso com tempos que não o presente ou imperfeito do indicativo (ou, na escrita, por vezes, com valor equivalente, futuro simples e condicional), é raro e arcaizante, mas ocorre por vezes. Alguns exemplos do CETEMPúblico:

> - Porque se a ideia fosse atacar a insulabridade das «ilhas», Almeida Garrett postulava a demolição de 7300 casas («não contando com os prédios do antigo Porto que **hajam de ser apeados** e que vão ruindo todos os anos»).
> - «Se no nosso testemunho e na nossa acção de bispos **houvéssemos de pensar** sempre o que pode dividir, nada ou muito pouco de útil poderíamos dizer ou fazer."
> - Eis a cópia fiel de alguns desses documentos, destinados a servirem de norma aos candidatos que **houverem de mostrar**-se aptos a serem providos nas funções que o orçamento remunera e que o Governo distribui:

Aqui, não me parece haver grande componente modal atribuível à perífrase; há mais um futuro indeterminado. Na primeira e na última frase poderiam usar-se perífrases com *vir* e na segunda com *ir*, com valores semelhantes.

Sobre o uso no Brasil, não me posso pronunciar muito, mas ainda há pouco ouvia *Pot Pourri: Amigo Urso/Resposta Do Amigo Urso* de *Gabriel, o Pensador*, que começa com:

> Amigo Urso, saudação polar
>   Ao leres esta, hás de te lembrar

Mas de qualquer forma, não era esse o objeto da pergunta.