# A modalidade do auxiliar 'haver de' uso no Brasil/Portugal

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

Como se dá a leitura de tal modo, no manual que consultei, o que me é limitado, li sendo usado em lugar de 'ter de' (dever), o que não li da equipe Ciberdúvidas em respostas a consulentes portugueses, apenas uma 'obrigação atenuada' nas palavras do consultor. Teria uso distinto Portugal/Brasil?

- No manual referido se encontra o seguinte exemplo atestado como tal:
  Tenho/hei de estudar (obrigação/necessidade)

Comment: Relacionada: [Haver-de + infinitivo em Portugal](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3329/2764).

Comment: Já havia lido isto e algo semelhante por Ciberdúvidas. A questão aqui presente é mais sobre a modalidade deôntica de obrigação com esta locução, que parece ser diferente o uso. Saliento: conforme o manual 'haver de' seria comutável por 'ter de', não meramente o que foi dito inclusive neste link 'obrigação atenuada'.

Comment: Sim, concordo que a pergunta é diferente. Mencionei a outra pergunta apenas a título de informação, não para sugerir que seria uma duplicada.

Comment: O problema é esse: Tenho de fazer algo se usa na fala e no escrito. haver de é bem formal e geralmente, não se fala (a não ser que fosse num tribunal, etc.). O uso é o mesmo. Porque seria diferente?

Answer (score 1):

*Tenho de estudar* e *hei de estudar* são coisas bem diferentes. A primeira indica necessidade ou obrigatoriedade (*preciso de estudar* ou *é minha obrigação estudar*).

A segunda indica de certa forma uma "obrigação atenuada", mas em forma de uma promessa ou compromisso fraco; essa promessa geralmente só envolve o locutor (não é o mesmo que *prometo-te que vou estudar*, em que se cria uma obrigação que a outra pessoa pode reclamar) -- pode ser só uma espécie de aspiração... Assim:

> Tenho andado muito ocupado com outras coisas, mas ainda hei de estudar esta noite.

=Comprometo-me a estudar algures durante esta noite. Dependendo do contexto, o valor modal pode não ser muito forte e ser mais uma exposição dos meus vagos planos para a noite. Mesmo indicando "esta noite", a ideia que dá é que a altura da noite em que se vai estudar não está bem definida. Por isso se associa a perífrase a um "futuro indeterminado".

> Não acabei a faculdade, mas ainda hei de (um dia) reingressar.

=É uma aspiração minha um dia, num futuro indeterminado, reingressar na faculdade e terminar o meu curso. Provavelmente nunca acontecerá.

Answer (score 1):

A [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9530/2764) do Jacinto já explica os usos de "tenho que/de" (necessidade/obrigatoriedade) e "hei de" (intenção/expectativa).

Sobre diferenças entre pt-PT e pt-BR, no Brasil "haver de" essencialmente não é usado, especialmente na linguagem falada, com exceção de citações literárias ou expressões quase fixas, como "Hei de vencer." e "Você há de me pagar.".